# MySQL summary table - evaluate and adjust

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I have a very simple summary table that sums up 2 fields in a table where records are collected at 15 minute intervals. So;

```
SELECT timevalue, SUM(value1)  AS sumvalue1, SUM(value2) AS sumvalue2 
FROM table 
GROUP BY timevalue
```

returns the results i would expect;

```
timevalue        sumvalue1  sumvalue2
-------------------------------------
16/08/2016 08:30    3000      200
16/08/2016 08:45    3200      150
16/08/2016 09:00    3100      400
16/08/2016 09:15    3300      450
16/08/2016 09:30    3400      600
```

My question is, is there a way to check that each sum value is never less than the previous value? and if it is return the sum from the previous timevalue? (so therefore the sumvalues are always the same or greater than the previous timevalue).

The results table should then look like this;

```
timevalue        sumvalue1  sumvalue2
-------------------------------------
16/08/2016 08:30    3000      200
16/08/2016 08:45    3200      200
16/08/2016 09:00    3200      400
16/08/2016 09:15    3300      450
16/08/2016 09:30    3400      600
```

I'm guessing i need some kind of if statement? Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the user defined variable and then doing some arithmetic something as

```
select timevalue,sumvalue_1 as sumvalue1, sumvalue_2 as sumvalue2 from
(
 select 
 timevalue,
 if(@prev_val1 = sumvalue1 or @prev_val1 > sumvalue1,@prev_val1,sumvalue1) as sumvalue_1,
 if(@prev_val2 = sumvalue2 or @prev_val2 > sumvalue2,@prev_val2,sumvalue2) as sumvalue_2,
 @prev_val1 := sumvalue1,
 @prev_val2 := sumvalue2
 from mytable,(select @prev_val1:=0,@prev_val2:=0)x
 order by timevalue
)x
order by timevalue
```

Here is a demo

```
create table mytable (
 timevalue datetime,
 sumvalue1 int,
 sumvalue2 int
);

insert into mytable values 
('2016-08-16 08:30:00',3000,200),
('2016-08-16 08:45:00',3200,150),
('2016-08-16 09:00:00',3100,400),
('2016-08-16 09:15:00',3300,450),
('2016-08-16 09:30:00',3400,600);


mysql> select * from mytable;
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| timevalue           | sumvalue1 | sumvalue2 |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2016-08-16 08:30:00 |      3000 |       200 |
| 2016-08-16 08:45:00 |      3200 |       150 |
| 2016-08-16 09:00:00 |      3100 |       400 |
| 2016-08-16 09:15:00 |      3300 |       450 |
| 2016-08-16 09:30:00 |      3400 |       600 |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now with the query

```
mysql> select timevalue,sumvalue_1 as sumvalue1, sumvalue_2 as sumvalue2 from
    -> (
    ->  select 
    ->  timevalue,
    ->  if(@prev_val1 = sumvalue1 or @prev_val1 > sumvalue1,@prev_val1,sumvalue1) as sumvalue_1,
    ->  if(@prev_val2 = sumvalue2 or @prev_val2 > sumvalue2,@prev_val2,sumvalue2) as sumvalue_2,
    ->  @prev_val1 := sumvalue1,
    ->  @prev_val2 := sumvalue2
    ->  from mytable,(select @prev_val1:=0,@prev_val2:=0)x
    ->  order by timevalue
    -> )x
    -> order by timevalue;
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| timevalue           | sumvalue1 | sumvalue2 |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2016-08-16 08:30:00 |      3000 |       200 |
| 2016-08-16 08:45:00 |      3200 |       200 |
| 2016-08-16 09:00:00 |      3200 |       400 |
| 2016-08-16 09:15:00 |      3300 |       450 |
| 2016-08-16 09:30:00 |      3400 |       600 |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi Abhik, the demo works great, however sumvalue1 and sumvalue 2 are calculated fields. If I add more values into mytable and then try change the sumvalue1 and sumvalue2 to sum(sumvalue1) and sum(sumvalue2) along with adding  group by timevalue I just get the actual calculated figures. Not the adjusted figures....

Comment: `select timevalue,sumvalue_1 as sumvalue1, sumvalue_2 as sumvalue2 from
(
 select
 timevalue, 
 if(@prev_val1 = sum(sumvalue1) or @prev_val1 > sum(sumvalue1),@prev_val1,sum(sumvalue1)) as sumvalue_1,
 if(@prev_val2 = sum(sumvalue2) or @prev_val2 > sum(sumvalue2),@prev_val2,sum(sumvalue2)) as sumvalue_2,
 @prev_val1 := sum(sumvalue1),
 @prev_val2 := sum(sumvalue2)
 from mytable,(select @prev_val1:=0,@prev_val2:=0)x
    group by timevalue 
 order by timevalue
)x

order by timevalue`

Comment: Yes you can modify the example query and place your original query as inner query something as instead of `from mytable` you can have ` from ( select your actual query)x,(....)`

Comment: Try as `select timevalue,sumvalue_1 as sumvalue1, sumvalue_2 as sumvalue2 from
(
 select 
 timevalue,
 if(@prev_val1 = sumvalue1 or @prev_val1 > sumvalue1,@prev_val1,sumvalue1) as sumvalue_1,
 if(@prev_val2 = sumvalue2 or @prev_val2 > sumvalue2,@prev_val2,sumvalue2) as sumvalue_2,
 @prev_val1 := sumvalue1,
 @prev_val2 := sumvalue2
 from (
   SELECT timevalue, SUM(value1)  AS sumvalue1, SUM(value2) AS sumvalue2 
   FROM table 
   GROUP BY timevalue 
 )y,(select @prev_val1:=0,@prev_val2:=0)x
 order by timevalue
)x
order by timevalue`

Comment: Sadly not 100% working after all. Works perfectly for 2 descending consecutive values however if there are 3 consecutive values the 3rd value will evaluate against the 2nd sum value and not the updated value (that was taken from the first value).  I hope that makes sense?!

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest example but still should work.

```
INSERT INTO SecondTable VALUES (
  NOW(),
  GREATEST(
    YOUR_SUM_1, (SELECT sumvalue1 FROM FirstTable ORDER BY timevalue DESC LIMIT 1)
  ),
  GREATEST(
    YOUR_SUM_2, (SELECT sumvalue2 FROM FirstTable ORDER BY timevalue DESC LIMIT 1)
  )
 );
```